# How does snapping work for Scale tool?

Tags: scale

When I try using snapping for scale it works only with Increment type (when Snap button is turned off and I keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed, with Snap button turned on snapping for Scale tool doesn't work at all). My question is: is there a way of snapping to vertex, face and edge while scaling in Object or Edit mode. Why does snapping work for Move tool and doesn't work for scaling? I don't believe that it can be so.

Comment: Hi, Vitalii. I hope you don't mind my edit. I hope that makes the question a bit clearer and I did not change any of the meaning you intended. If you don't think any part of it is helpful please forgive me and use the edit link to edit the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Changes have been made to improve the way snapping works.
You can now choose which type of snap affects transformations.

In the snap popover towards the bottom activate *Scale* to use vertex snapping while scaling objects.

[image]

Comment: Ow man thanks, people in Blender community are brilliant)